# OData: limit query fields?

Tags: odata

is there an option in OData/EF to limit the fields a user can perform queries on (with for example `$filter`)? We have got big tables and don't want to put indexes on all (combinations of) table columns.

Comment: Update in 2018: [Limit OData $filter by property in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52040901/8601760)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit OData $filter by property in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040901/limit-odata-filter-by-property-in-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this type of limits. You can analyze the query yourself though. Either by looking at the incomming URL, or by analyzing the LINQ expression executed against the provider.

Answer (score -1):

Now you can use top and skip options

```
$top=10&$skip=0
```

they work just like in SQL

Read more about [Top](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#43_Top_System_Query_Option_top) and [skip](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#44_Skip_System_Query_Option_skip)